# applying css to html tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply specific css styles to two separate Wordpress pages. I have a header.php and header-int.php for my index page and interior pages.

I need the css on my home page to have

```
  html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }
```

and the interior page css to be

```
    html, body {
     overflow: auto;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
```

I can only seem to apply it to the body tag, either in the css sheet or hard coded, but can't seem to apply it to the html as well. Not sure the proper way to target the html general tag
        }

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to select ALL elements.

Comment: What you have is okay. If it doesn't work, it may be because it's overridden in another stylesheet. Your browser should provide you with the tools to inspect the elements and their styling so you can find out what causes this.

Comment: Since the only difference is the `overflow` property, applying that via the [WordPress body tags](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) should get you there.

Comment: the problem is that's what I want to happen, but since the css stylesheets are loaded cronilogically one style will override the other so one wont be applied. I need to somehow apply html styles in the html, but can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each wordpress page will have unique page-class in body tag.
You can target from that.

**For Example:**

***Homepage:***

```
<body class="home page page-id-5 page-template-default single-author">
.....
</body>
```

You can target the home page body like

```
 body.page-id-5 {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }
```

Comment: will i always be id 5 or do i use home

Comment: In each wordpress page you will have unique class " page-id-* " (* - it will vary). And for home page you will have class in body tag as "home".